# PInvoke overloading, passing address of array offset to unmanaged library

Tags: c#, pinvoke

(Talking to a vendor library that talks to a device over Ethernet.  Library can read and write flash but only 512 bytes at a time.)

I have two questions:

Is specifying 'EntryPoint' the right way to "overload" a DLL entry point?

Is there any (correct) way to get the offset into an array without pinning the array first?

I realize this ground has been more or less covered from different angles before, but perhaps a little reinforcement wouldn't hurt.

```
public class DevSector {
   const int _SectorSize = 0x00010000;
   const int _CommBufSiz = 0x00000200;

   public void Read(byte[] buf, long addr, CDev dev) {
      PinnedBuffer pbuf = new PinnedBuffer(buf);
      for (int offset = 0; offset < _SectorSize; offset += _CommBufSize) {
         int cnt = _CommBufSize;
         ReadBuf(dev, addr + offset, pbuf, offset, ref cnt);
      }
   }

   [DllImport("Dev.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint="Dev_ReadData")]
   static extern int Dev_ReadUint(IntPtr h, long addr, ref uint val, ref uint size);

   bool ReadUint(CDev dev, long addr, ref uint val) {
      uint size = 4;
      return(
       Dev.eResult.Success ==
       (Dev.eResult)Dev_ReadUint(dev.Handle, addr, ref val, ref size)
      );
   }

   [DllImport("Dev.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint="Dev_ReadData"))]
   static extern int Dev_ReadBuf(IntPtr h, long addr, IntPtr ptr, ref uint size);

   bool ReadBuf(CDev dev, long addr, PinnedBuffer buf, int offset, ref uint size) {
      return(Dev.eResult.Success == (Dev.eResult)Dev_ReadBuf(
       dev.Handle, addr, buf.Ptr(offset), ref size
      ));
   }

   public class PinnedBuffer {
      public GCHandle GCH;
      public byte[] Buf;
      public PinnedBuffer(byte[] buf) {
         Buf = buf;
         GCH = GCHandle.Alloc(Buf, GCHandleType.Pinned);
      }
      public IntPtr Ptr(int offset) {
         return Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(Buf, offset);
      }
      ~PinnedBuffer() {
         if (!(GCH.IsAllocated)) {
            return;
         }
         GCH.Free();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Answers to 2 questions:

1. Is specifying 'EntryPoint' the right way to "overload" a DLL entry point?

   Yes, perfectly ok.
2. Is there any (correct) way to get the offset into an array without pinning the array first?

   No, but if you don't mind using "unsafe", you could do it using a raw byte pointer.

Like this (error checking omitted):

```
public void Read(byte[] buf, long addr, CDev dev) 
{
    unsafe
    {
        fixed (byte* bufPtr = buf)
        {
            for (int offset = 0; offset < _SectorSize; offset += _CommBufSize, bufPtr += _ComBuffSize) 
            {
                int cnt = _CommBufSize;
                Dev_ReadBuf(dev.Handle, addr + offset, (IntPtr)bufPtr, ref cnt);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is specifying 'EntryPoint' the right way to "overload" a DLL entry point?

It's one way to do it. The other way is to use standard overloading. You can declare pinvokes with the same name but different parameters. So long as the parameters are logically equivalent you will be fine. For instance you can write:

```
[DllImport(...)]
static int extern Foo(ref int bar);

[DllImport(...)]
static int extern Foo(IntPtr bar);
```

> Is there any (correct) way to get the offset into an array without pinning the array first?

I do not know of one. Clearly the array must be pinned. And once you've pinned it, what else are you going to do other than add the offset to the address of the first element?